# why Jetbrain Idea community version has a different view of ultimate one?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

[image]

1st is community version, 2nd is ultimate version.

why the `6. TODO` window behave different ?

Is that a ultimate feature? or just I make a different setting ?

the difference is, 1st view is like:

```
----------------------
 project  |  editor
----------------------
        TODO
----------------------
```

2nd view is like:

```
----------------------
          |  editor
 project  |-----------
          |  TODO
----------------------
```

Comment: The community version does not have the same features as ultimate.  The former is free, while the latter is paid.  If you want full functionality you'll have to buy a license (which I will tell you is well worth the money).

Comment: How is TODO different? Your screen is from indexing phase...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure this:

> Preferences   |   Appearance & Behavior   |   [Appearance](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/appearance.html):

Under section **Window Options** there is checkbox **Widescreen tool window layout**:

[image: Appearance settings]

see more about this option https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/appearance.html#wide

> Widescreen tool window layout is OFF:
>   [image: Widescreen tool window layout is OFF (preview)]
>
> Widescreen tool window layout is ON:
>   [image: Widescreen tool window layout is ON (preview)]